# Azuredevops Repo Api to get updated yaml parameters from external apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, jfrog-cli

We have a java based ticket management application and where users can submit the input values   "projectname", "accesskind", "permissiontype". We have a azuredevops pipeline created to automate the permission assignment in jfrog artifactory, where the [pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421187/how-to-verify-existence-of-resources-and-components-in-jfrog-artifactory) is currently configured with manual input of these values to the yaml file parameters from the Tickets.

Our Ticket management tool have capability to push the contents of these values over API calls. So I am looking for Azuredevops server Repo API, that I can give to the tools to update this values directly in the pipeline parameter yaml files, from there I can integrate  my existing pipelines

Comment: Are you looking for the API call to modify a file in a Git repository in Azure DevOps?

Comment: yes.. want to modify azurepipeline paramaters values, so that the build will be triggered